# Q: How to use domain docomposition on a Matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

How would I go about separating a grid into 4 so that different threads can access it? Not so much a question on the code, just on the process.

I need to parrallelize Conway's game of life for a homework project, to do this I learned that I have to separate the grid into 4 (number of threads) subgrids. In this sense it would have a upper-left, upper-right, lower-left and lower-right subgrid.

Should I just restrain the use of certain cells with variables? like so

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(New_grid, Current_grid) private(i, j) num_threads(threads)
int thread_num     = omp_get_thread_num();
int thread_start_y = get_starting_point_y(thread_num);
int thread_start_x = get_starting_point_x(thread_num);
for(i = thread_start_y; i < tread_start_y + half_height; ++i){
    for(j = thread_start_x; j < thread_start_x + half_width; ++j){
        New_grid[i][j] = calculate_new_state(Current_grid)
    }
}
```

or do I have to make copies of the sub grids and not join them until asked to? (very incomplete mini code since the subgrids would have to share memory)

```
int sub_grid[height/2][width/2]; //suppose even numbers
#pragma omp parallel shared(Current_grid) private(i, j, New_sub_grid, thread_num) num_threads(threads)

int thread_num     = omp_get_thread_num();
sub_grid           = copy_subgrid(Current_grid, thread_num);

for(i = 0; i < tread_start_y + half_height; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < width/2; ++j){
        New_sub_grid[i][j] = calculate_new_state(sub_grid)
    }
}
```

or are both wrong?

Comment: The first idea coming to me is, you need concept of incomplete/partial cell state for border cells, and separate pass to combine them after bordering subgrids are complete. Several slightly different ways to implement this come to mind, too.

Comment: First solution is the most flexible. Especially, as mentioned Hyde, for the processing of borders. IIRC, Conway model is synchronous and all cells are updated simultaneously. The best way to do that is to have two arrays: present and future, You compute future as a function of present and you exchange their role (or copy future to present). This largely limits the amount of synchronizations that you have to manage.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the first one then, thank you!